# Error using Jquery datepicker in ASP.Net

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am trying to use the jquery datepicker in my asp.net solution but receive the following error:

Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'datepick'

I have the following markup in the head section of the site.master file:

```
 <script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.datepick.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#startdate').datepick({ dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yyyy' });
            $('#enddate').datepick({ dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yyyy' });
        });    
    </script>
```

And the following markup within a CheckProgress.aspx page:

```
   <div id="content">
                        From
                        <asp:TextBox ID="startdate" class="field" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
                        To
                        <asp:TextBox ID="enddate" class="field" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
```

I tried loads of different things - putting the script tags inline with the div itself and moving the textboxes to different pages, but I end up getting the same error. I have checked that the jquery code paths are correct and also tried using the jquery files in a brand new asp.net solution where it works without error!

Any ideas how to debug this or determine what is happening here?

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
  $(function () {
            $('#startdate').datepick({ dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yyyy' });
            $('#enddate').datepick({ dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yyyy' });
        });
```

to

```
  $(function () {
            $('#startdate').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yyyy' });
            $('#enddate').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yyyy' });
        });
```

and include the jquery UI js

downloadit form here http://jqueryui.com/

Comment: what files exactly do I need to include? I tried to include jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.min.js and added a reference to it in the scripts folder but still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

use like that

```
<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.datepick.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#<%=startdate.ClientID %>').datepick({ dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yyyy' });
            $('#<%=enddate.ClientID %>').datepick({ dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yyyy' });
        });    
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.datepick.js"></script>
```

Some plugin created by your own? I have not idea what the  is, there are only  class in jQuery UI. Check those demos:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Answer (score 0):

Try to include script as absolute path. 
src="scripts/jquery.datepick.js"
change this
http://localhost:8080/scripts/jquery/datepicker.js

may be answer is simple as your web page does not include this file. Try to load your aspx file with (firefox web developer, google chrome or fiddler) to see if your javascript file is really included.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to use jQuery UI's datepicker, you must:

Include both jQuery and jQuery UI (the latter requires both JS and CSS),

```
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.12/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.12/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

declare the textbox in your ASPX markup

```
<asp:TextBox ID="DatePicker" runat="server" />
```

and wire up the datepicker to the textbox.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%= this.DatePicker.ClientID %>").datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

Remember, this script block must appear *after* the inclusion of jQuery and jQuery UI otherwise it won't work.